# System.out.print doesnt display customer data

Tags: java

I am writing a client database. I want to know the customer's name and hometown based on the customer number. When I enter number 2, I want to see Arya Stark, Edinburgh and when I enter number 1, I want to see Jon Snow, London. Why doesn't my program work? How to fix this?

```
package app;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Person {
    String name;
    String homeCity;
    int customerNumber;
}

public class Customers {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;

        System.out.print ("Give a customer card number: ");
        name = input.next();

        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.name = "Jon Snow";
        person1.homeCity = "London";
        person1.customerNumber = 1;

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.name = "Arya Stark";
        person2.homeCity = "Edinburgh";
        person2.customerNumber = 2;

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: where do you print your customer?

Comment: Println requires arguments to print anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Currently your code: 1) Asks for some user input, which it stores in the `name` variable; 2) Creates and initializes two `Person` objects; 3) Prints an empty line to the console. I suggest you make sure you understand every line of your current code, and why it's not currently printing any information - then you can work on fixing the problem.

Comment: You forgot to implement the entire logic for *retrieving* (and printing) a "customer" / "customer" data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```java
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String homeCity;
    private int customerNumber;

    public Person(String name, String homeCity, int customerNumber) {
      this.name = name;
      this.homeCity = homeCity;
      this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }

    public boolean isMatch(int num) {
      return num == customerNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return name + " from " + homeCity; 
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person1 = new Person("Jon Snow", "London", 1);
        Person person2 = new Person("Arya Stark", "Edinburgh", 2);

        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Give a customer card number: ");
            String num = input.next();

            if (person1.isMatch(Integer.parseInt(num))) {
                System.out.println(person1);
            } else if (person2.isMatch(Integer.parseInt(num))) {
                System.out.println(person2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```